# How to get redirect the given, correct and clean URL after Facebook authentication in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, redirect, url-rewriting, facebook-authentication

I am developing a functionality to allow facebook users to register in our web application. The approach is:

We will create one app on facebook
Facebook authentication plugin (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) will be used in our registration page.
When user clicks on facebook button, facebook login page and then app authorization page are shown.
One user allows/disallows facebook app, user will be redirected to the main page(https://example.com)

But it's redirected like this([https://example.com/#*=*](https://example.com/#_=_)), so I am facing another issue with that.
Appended this characters(#*=*)
I have tried to fix the url, but it's redirected like that anyway.
Here is the redirection code.

```
       Auth::login($user);
       return Redirect::to(URL('/'));
```

My server is Nginx.
Hope to get solved my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to name the route then redirect to it.

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')- 
>name('home');
```

then `redirect()->to(route('home'));`